# Datetime to seasons

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have an example data as :

```
datetime.            column1

2021-04-01 01:00.     11
2021-04-05 02:00.     10
2021-04-12 03:00.      1
2021-04-11 04:00.      5
2021-04-07 05:00.      20
```

I would like to create a new column called season which outputs cooling season if the datetime values is between the month of May and September, while heating season if the datetime values are between october and April. The example output should look like this:

```
datetime.            column1.  seasons

2021-01-01 01:00.     11.       Heating season
2021-05-01 02:00.     10.       Cooling season
2021-12-01 03:00.      1.       Heating season
2021-11-01 04:00.      5.       Heating season
2021-07-01 05:00.      20.      Cooling season
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways,

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
```

**With np.select with specific conditions for months**

```
conditions = [
    df.datetime.dt.month.isin(np.arange(5,10)),
    (df.datetime.dt.month.isin(np.arange(1,5))) | (df.datetime.dt.month.isin(np.arange(10,13))),
]
choices = ['Cooling season','Heating season']
df['seasons'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
df
```

**With np.select with a default**

```
conditions = [
    df.datetime.dt.month.isin(np.arange(5,10)),
]
choices = ['Cooling season']
df['seasons'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Heating season')
df
```

**With np.where**

```
df['seasons'] = np.where(df.datetime.dt.month.isin(np.arange(5,10)), 'Cooling season','Heating season')
df
```

**Output**

```
    datetime            column1     seasons
0   2021-01-01 01:00:00 11      Heating season
1   2021-05-01 02:00:00 10      Cooling season
2   2021-12-01 03:00:00 1       Heating season
3   2021-11-01 04:00:00 5       Heating season
4   2021-07-01 05:00:00 20      Cooling season
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["seasons"] = np.where((df["datetime"].dt.month >= 5) 
                          & (df["datetime"].dt.month <= 9),
                         "Cooling season", "Heating season")
```

```
>>> df
             datetime  column1         seasons
0 2021-01-01 01:00:00       11  Heating season
1 2021-05-05 02:00:00       10  Cooling season
2 2021-12-12 03:00:00        1  Heating season
3 2021-11-11 04:00:00        5  Heating season
4 2021-07-07 05:00:00       20  Cooling season
```

Comment: Just a thought, iterating over datetime column twice with & condition might slow down the things.